# Interview on network connections

Tags: networking, routing, subnet, static-routes

I was on an interview for a web developer position and for some reason, in the test, there was a question about networks that sounded like this:

> Your PC ip address is (--something like--) 192.168.0.2 and you are
>   trying to access a shared directory from a PC with the ip address
>   (--something like--) 10.10.0.2. The connection is refused (--I don't really
>   remember if "refused" was the word, but they said that the connection
>   somehow didn't succeed--) . What is the most probable cause?

How would you respond to this question in an interview?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on a different [subnet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subnetwork) and there is no entry in [routing table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Routing_table) that would allow you to see destination. Possible solutions are either to unite two subnets into one (this is not optimal, since it involves changing network topology). Or add a route to routing table of your PC or router, depending on requirements

Comment: Thank you for your excelent answer. How bad is it if I answered that I'm on a different network? :)

Comment: Well, the way, the question is phrased makes me assume that your PC and destiantion shared directory are on the same _physical_ network. I think _subnet_ was the keyword that they wanted to hear. You could clearly see it from difference in IP addresses

Answer (score 1):

If the connection was refused (an active access denial), it means the service you're trying to access isn't running, or, you're not authorized to use it.  It also means that the other system is online, not powered off, and routing has been set up properly between the two networks.

The network can come under suspicion only when connections time out, or perform poorly.